# How to use the latest kubectl-convert to update a file on disk

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to update bunch of ingress.yaml files in my microservices project to use the new kubernetes API version. Currently the ingresses are using `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` still.

I'm confused with the plugin (`kubectl convert`) and the whole new binary (`kubectl-convert`)... Which tool should I be using in 2023?

I would like to have a one liner command to update all `ingress.yaml` files recursively inside current directory.

Maybe the new tool has some bugs in it? I'm getting this error with the bash script I assumed would work:

```
find . -name "ingress.yaml" | while read file; do kubectl-convert -f "$file" > "$file"; done
error: no objects passed to convert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use `kubectl convert` plugin and the following cmd should do the trick for you:

```
find . -name "ingress.yaml" | while read file; do kubectl convert -f "$file" --output-version networking.k8s.io/v1 > "$file".bak && mv "$file".bak "$file"; done
```

Tested locally on a set of 3 ingress.yaml file nested within different sub-folders.

I've assumed you're moving from `extensions/v1beta1` to `networking.k8s.io/v1`.

As is the general practice, make sure to back up your files before running this (or any such) command, in case of any unexpected issues.

Hope this helps.